# update bit datatype value in database

Tags: c#, .net

```
try
        {
            UserMaster ObjUserMst = new UserMaster();
            ObjUserMst.GetData("UPDATE  MemberDetails SET Active = 0  WHERE Member_No = '" + txtmemberno.Text + "'");
            MessageBox.Show("Installment Close Successfully.", "Close Installment", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            btndebit.Visible = true;
            btndebit.Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "btncloseinstallment_Click", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

its get data code

```
public DataTable GetData(string Query)
    {


        string cn = GlobalClass.ConnectionStringGet();
        Con = new SqlConnection(cn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Con;
        if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
        }
        SqlTransaction ObjTrans = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = ObjTrans;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = Query;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;

        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dreader);
        Con.Close();
        Con.Dispose();
        return dt;

    }
```

i have winforms.
i have `memberdetails` Table - in this `Active` Field & its datatype is `BIT`.
 its
default value is `1`. but i need to update it to `0`.
1 = ture
0 = false
when i tried above code `Active` Field data didnt update
but i got message `"Installment Close Successfully."`
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkuhW.png 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToXFV.png
I upload my images on above link

help me guys.. sorry if i didnt explain very well bcz i m new here

Comment: So no exception is being thrown and its successful?

Comment: ya but i think its just given message without update.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @AlpeshSavaliya Although you said you got it, but I strongly recommend you to read my answer and hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got it.

```
        string constring = GlobalClass.ConnectionStringGet();
        string sqlUpdate = "UPDATE  MemberDetails SET Active = '0'  WHERE Member_No = '" + txtmemberno.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, conDatabase);
        conDatabase.Open();
        cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conDatabase.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Installment Close Successfully.");
```

its update `Active` Field `1` to `0` successfully.